# Synchronize repository from Github

Tags: netbeans, github

I'm trying to synchronize Netbeans And Git repository but without success because I have all the time some Java Error. So I download Git for Windows and make everything in Tutorial. I downloaded everything so I make a project in Netbeans. I'm trying to synchronize everything from program from GIT for windows but unfortunately when I'm trying to see my repository in Git I have this error message:

**"Failed looking for HEAD int this repository"**

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you see a `.git` in your Netbean project root directory?

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using?